# Neutral-Phase reversal

Tags: three-phase

Could anybody suggest solution for a situation where, In a 3-phase, 4-wire system, phase and neutral are getting interchanged. How can I prevent this situation and what is it exactly called!?

Comment: Usually you can avoid that by proper training of the persons dealing with it. When it happens, I usually call it incompetence.

Comment: Please elaborate on the affected appliance (household, industrial). "Getting interchanged" and "How [to] prevent" sound like it's happening _right now_? Do you expect us to make those electricians stop what they're doing or do you just want why that is and how to correct the installation? I think this is an interesting situation, though I don't know what you expect the community to answer (answers could be quite broad).

Answer (score 0):

You can use color codes if your installation uses it. However, I'd rather use a multimeter to be sure because *-from my short experience-* you're not sure if the technician did actually use color codes.
I've seen a phase conductor connected to a socket through an earth color coded conductor (Yellow/Green) because the technician ran out maybe of other colors :)

Comment: Any electrician who uses "earth-colored" wires for phase should be fried, or at least fired, but preferrably fried.

Answer (score 0):

In EU we have black color for phase wires, blue for neutral and yellow/green for earth wire. 
You can't swap the neutral with line, this can be a deadly mistake. You'd better hire somebody or stop doing this, please.

Comment: We also use brown for phase.

Answer (score 0):

The old EU system was Black or brown for 3 phase lines.  To prevent wiring errors, the new standard is **Brown, Black, Grey** for L1,L2,L3 and in America, **Red, Yellow, Blue** colours are used. (RYB)

In applications where reverse rotating machines are hazardous to people or equipment, one will include a  three-phase monitor relay.
[image]
This protection consists of different RC passive filters that use phase shifting currents to activate a relay which in turn powers the 3 phase contactors when in the proper sequence or activates a light indicator if faulty.